# Custom Exception in Spring boot Application Fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to customize my response object when an Exception occurs (As by default it will reveal context path and other technical details in response). I found that we can use @ControllerAdvice annotation to achieve this.

But the problem I have is I want to throw a customized exception whenever a HttpMessageNotReadableException occurs. I tried something like below. But the Spring application was failed to start.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<ExceptionResDto> handleException(){
        ExceptionResDto response = new ExceptionResDto();
        .......
        return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionResDto>(response, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

But if I have done something like this, it works!!! (Overriding currently available method to catch HttpMessageNotReadableException)

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    .... //customized code
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, new HttpHeaders(), status);
}
```

My question is @ExceptionHandler(value = {CustomException.class}) only used for custom exceptions? Can't be used to existing more general exceptions? In order to customize such general exceptions, do we always need to override their original exception handling methods?

Following is the log result.

```
(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
2020-05-03 14:38:41.565 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication -
                Application startup failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity lk.crm.dialog.config.CustomExceptionHandler.myHandleException(), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at lk.crm.dialog.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity lk.crm.dialog.config.CustomExceptionHandler.myHandleException(), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]: {protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity lk.crm.dialog.config.CustomExceptionHandler.myHandleException(), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:245)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:826)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$901be0b6.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$41(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$901be0b6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b8bb3bfc.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$901be0b6.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to throw another exception inside your exception handler?
I guess what you want is to catch the thrown exception in a central place ( Your handler ), maybe log the error with more details ( I would definetly recommend doing this) and give an imediate response to the client with summed up details.

Instead of throwing another exception, throw a custom exception model which holds the content you like to return in a json format.

```
    public class CustomExceptionModel{

    private String message
    private HttpStatus httpStatus
    private ZonedTime timestamp

    public Custom{ExceptionModel (String message, HttpStatus httpStatus){
this.message = message;
this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
this.timeStamp = ZonedTime.now();
    }
    }
```

Your handler yould look like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<ExceptionResDto> handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex){
       log.severe("Put details here ;) ");
        return new ResponseEntity<CustomExceptionModel>(new CustomExceptionModel(ex.getMessage(), ex.getStatus()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

This whill throw a Json as exception exactly with the content you need. I recommend using a timestamp, a message with pretty general reason ( I mean not the whole stacktrace. This you can place in your log.severe () for exampe and the httpStatuscode. I know the status code is also added in the responseEntity Object but I like to have it displayed in the json.

**Update:**
I've just seen that you call your Exception handling method "handleException". As you correctly extend ResponseEntityExceptionhandler you already a method that is named the same way. So spring gets confused. Try to rename your exception handling method. I prefer to use the name of the exception and prefex it with handle like handleHttpMethodNotReadableException.
 Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the repy. I do not want to throw exception inside my @ExceptionHandler body. Rather I want exact scenario like u mentioned. But if I come up with a solution like above, the spring application fails to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the Logs?

Comment: It a bit lengthy. I added the logs from the point where application fails. Updated my question.

Comment: I have changed the name of my exception handling method. But still getting the same error. By the way there was no spring exception handling method called handleException. There is a one called handleExceptionInternal.